# what does "atmospheric navigation" refers to?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

what does "atmospheric navigation" refers to?

So, too, this seer, in reply to a query regarding what was then termed
**"atmospheric navigation,"** felt "deeply impressed" that "the necessary
mechanism—to transcend the adverse currents of air, so that we may
sail as easily and safely and pleasantly as birds—is dependent on a new
motive power. This power will come. It will not only move the
locomotive on the rail, and the carriage on the country road, but the
aerial cars also, which will move through the sky from country to
country."

Source: [The History of Spiritualism](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ghqqNPvWHIQC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=seer+atmospheric+navigation&source=bl&ots=Bvj1yfV2A_&sig=ACfU3U2oZ_K6-G910KZrZY3_LoSvyKrSKA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp_YzRzcLnAhV8UBUIHay4Bg0Q6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=seer%20atmospheric%20navigation&f=false) by Arthur Conan Doyle.

Comment: "Air travel", basically.

Comment: Bear in mind, there were no airplanes then.  travel through the atmosphere, an early way of saying this.

Answer (score 1):

"Air travel", basically. There were no airplanes then. travel through the atmosphere, an early way of saying this.– stevekeiretsu, Lambie

Answer (score -1):

This is a term being used for the projects of UAV (Unmanned Areial Vehicles) for transmitting wireless Internet free of charge now.

Pls look at *https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?2149212-Atmospheric-Navigation-for-UAV-s*. It seems to be useful.

Or, read *The history of Spiritualism* to answer your question. The term you asked about is outdated.

Comment: Arthur Conan Doyle certainly wasn't writing about wireless Internet transmitters.

Comment: Though, he seemed to dream about something like that. In terms of aeronautics, at least.